# What's the best way to get from Dresden (Germany) to Krakow/Katowice (Poland)?

Tags: europe, germany, transportation, poland, krakow

There seems to be no direct train / flight connection, and the bus would take like forever. Google tells me [it's just a 4h drive](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Katowice,+Poland/Dresden,+Germany/@50.4334777,15.1918492,8z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x4716ce2336a1ccd1:0xb9af2a350559fabb!2m2!1d19.0237815!2d50.2648919!1m5!1m1!1s0x4709cf29101ad6a9:0x421b1cb4288feb0!2m2!1d13.7372621!2d51.0504088!3e0), but I couldn't find a good way to get there without a car.

What would be the preferred route that is

1. fast
2. not too expensive
3. does not include too many intermediate stops (and does not rely on short transition times)

Comment: Also, we can't really tell you what is "best." We need more specific guidelines than "fast" and "not to expensive".  What is expensive to you may be a bargain for someone else. Can you tell us a specific budget and a specific timeline you're aiming for?

Comment: Seems (to me) like the 'best' would be to drive (rental car), but a good ole' thumb might do it too

Answer (score 3):

According [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Dresden/Krakow), your options are:

1. Train + bus through Wroclaw (7.5 hours)

[image]

2. Train through Wroclaw (9.5 hours)

[image]

3. [Car rental](http://www.kayak.com/cars)/[car sharing](https://www.blablacar.com/) (6.5 hours)

[image]

Comment: @faad, please don't forget to 'accept' Jonathan's answer if you're all set now.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers